# Product rule for matrices

Tags: matrices, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus

Let:

- $x$ be a vector of dimension $n \times 1$.
- A be a matrix of dimension $n \times m$.

I want to find the derivative of $x^T  A$ w.r.t. $x$.

By both the numerator and denominator conventions, the derivative of $x^T$ w.r.t. $x$ seems to be the $n  \times  n$ identity matrix.

By the product rule, $d(x^T \cdot A) = d(x^T) \cdot A + x^T \cdot d(A) $.

$d(A)$ is $0$, and since $d(x^T) = I_n$, the expression should reduce to just $A$.

But Wikipedia claims it's actually $A^T$.

What did I miss/do wrong?

Comment: are you sure that $A$ is $n \times m$?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $x^TAx$ is a function $\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ so the claim that the derivative is $A^T$ does not make sense. (Also $A$ has to be square for this to make sense.)

Now, $$f(x)=x^TAx=\sum\limits_{i,j}a_{i,j}x_ix_j $$ and so differentiating with respect to $x_i$ gives us $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}f(x) = \sum_{j=1}^na_{i,j}x_j + \sum_{j=1}^na_{j,i}x_j= e_i^T(A+A^T)x.$$

The derivative is then $\nabla f = x^T(A^T+A).$

Comment: How would I derive that in a "coordinate-free" way, in the sense that I'd rather not refer to the elements of the matrices as much as possible, since most of the point of this is to avoid messy index manipulation?

Comment: Although, I didn't ask for the derivative of $x^T A x$, but $x^T A$.

Comment: @AlokSingh "I want to find the derivative of $x^TAx$ w.r.t. $x.$"

Comment: In regards to your question about why you get $A$ but it should be $A^T$, it is arguably a matter of convention. The function $x^TA$ outputs row vectors, but when talking about functions between finite dimensional spaces we usually talk in column vectors. This swap in row and column vectors corresponds to taking the transpose $A^T$. So if we write the function $f(x)=x^TA$ in the usual convention we get $f(x)=A^Tx.$

Comment: Oops. Fixed that.