# How to prove the diference of the gradients of $f$ and its quadratic approximation at $a$ is $o(||x-a||^2)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

So consider that $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is ${\cal C}^{\infty}$ and all the derivatives are bounded. ($||D^kf(x)||\leq M$ for all $k$)

Consider a quadratic aproximation around a point $a$:
$$ q(x) = f(a) + \nabla f(a)^T(x-a) + \frac{1}{2}(x-a)^T\nabla^2 f(a)(x-a).$$

I know that $f(x) - q(x) = o(||x-a||^2)$.
I'd like to prove that $\nabla f(x) = \nabla q(x) + o(||x-a||^2)$ as well, under the hypotheses.

However, the remainder theorems give me something like $f(x) = q(x) + r(x)$ with $r(x) = \frac{1}{6}D^3(a+\xi(x-a))(x-a)^3$, which is $O(||x-a||^3)$ for limited third order derivatives, but differentiating it, I only get
$$ \nabla f(x) = \nabla q(x) + \frac{1}{6}\left[ 3D^3(a+\xi(x-a))(x-a)^2 + D\left(D^3(a+\xi(x-a))\right)(x-a)^3\right]...$$
Even when all derivatives are bounded, there is that first term that seems that is $O(||x-a||^2)$, so I can't conclude that $f(x) - q(x) = o(||x-a||^2)$... Is there another way to do this?

Comment: @WilliamM. In the example you gave the bounded derivative condition does not hold.

Comment: I don't get it? What example?

Comment: There was a comment (that is now deleted) that presented $f(x) = e^{x}$ as a counterexample to the statement you are trying to prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f:\mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}$ has [continuous derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative#Total_derivative,_total_differential_and_Jacobian_matrix) of all order, with $\|D^kf(x)\|\leq M$. Then $f':\mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}^m$ also has continuous derivatives of all order, with $\|D^kf'(x)\|\leq M$.

We note that, for each fixed $x$, $f'(x):\mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}$ is viewed as the linear transform given by $$f'(x)h=\nabla f(x)^Th,\quad h\in \mathbb{R}^m,$$ while $$f''(x):\mathbb{R}^m\times \mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}$$ is viewed as the bilinear transform given by $$f''(x)(h,k)=k^T\nabla^2 f(x)h,\quad h\in \mathbb{R}^m,$$

The [Taylor series in several variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Taylor_series_in_several_variables) of $f'(x)$ is given by $$f'(x)=f'(a)+f''(a)(x-a)+\frac{1}{2!}f'''(a)(x-a)^2+\cdots.\tag{1}$$

Using this notation, if $$q(x) = f(a) + \nabla f(a)^T(x-a) + \frac{1}{2}(x-a)^T\nabla^2 f(a)(x-a),$$ or $$q(x) = f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) + \frac{1}{2}f''(a)(x-a)^2,$$
then $$q'(x) =f'(a) + \frac{1}{2}2f''(a)(x-a).\tag{2}$$

It follows from $(1)$ and $(2)$ that $$f'(x)=q'(x)+O(\|x-a\|^2).$$

**Note:** The calculation in $(2)$ uses this [Product rule for matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2080240/product-rule-for-matrices#answer-2080258). You can find related discussions searching for ''\(\|Xw-y\|^2\) derivative'' on SearchOnMath.

Comment: I see... So I guess you can't get little o instead of big, then... It's a bit counterintuitive that you can get it for the difference of the functions but not for the difference of the gradients.